# How to get accurate distance estimations using Beacons

Tags: android, beacon, altbeacon, rssi, eddystone

I am trying to develop an Android application that calculates the position between 3 Eddystone beacons.

I have my 3 beacons:

```
    final double BEACON_1_X = 0.50, BEACON_1_Y = 6.38;
    Identifier BEACON_1_ID = Identifier.parse("0x111111111111");
    final double BEACON_2_X = 5.86, BEACON_2_Y = 0.1;
    Identifier BEACON_2_ID = Identifier.parse("0x222222222222");
    final double BEACON_3_X = 0.05, BEACON_3_Y = 2.63;
    Identifier BEACON_3_ID = Identifier.parse("0x333333333333");
```

I am using the AltBeacon library in order to calculate the distance from the scanning device to the beacons.

Here is my code which I use in order to scan for the beacons and calculate the position according to the beacons.

```
for (Beacon beacon : beacons) {
                    if (!uuids.contains(beacon)) {
                        uuids.add(beacon);
                        noBeacons.setText("" + ++beaconsFound);
                    }

                    // If the beacon we see uses the Eddystone-UID frame
                    if (beacon.getServiceUuid() == 0xfeaa && beacon.getBeaconTypeCode() == 0x00) {
                        curr_dist = Double.parseDouble(df.format(beacon.getDistance()));
                        
                        if(beacon.getId2().equals(BEACON_1_ID)){
                           BEACON_1_DISTANCE = curr_dist;
                        } else if (beacon.getId2().equals(BEACON_2_ID)) {
                            BEACON_2_DISTANCE = curr_dist;
                        } else if (beacon.getId2().equals(BEACON_3_ID)) {
                            BEACON_3_DISTANCE = curr_dist;
                            if (BEACON_1_DISTANCE != 0 && BEACON_2_DISTANCE != 0){
                                calculatePosition(BEACON_1_DISTANCE,BEACON_2_DISTANCE,BEACON_3_DISTANCE);
                                logger.append("\nUser Position ("+SCANNER_X + ", " + SCANNER_Y + ")");
                            }
                        }
                        // Show its id and distance
//                        String item = "id: " + beacon.getId2() + ", distance: " + curr_dist + " m.";
//                        logger.append("\n" + item);
                    }
                }
```

Now in order to calculate the position I have this function: (I have found this formula on the internet that finds the position from 3 known distances so I suppose it's correct)

```
    void calculatePosition(double d1, double d2,double d3) {
        double A = 2*BEACON_2_X - 2*BEACON_1_X;
        double B = 2*BEACON_2_Y - 2*BEACON_1_Y;
        double C = d1*d1 - d2*d2 - BEACON_1_X*BEACON_1_X + BEACON_2_X*BEACON_2_X - BEACON_1_Y*BEACON_1_Y + BEACON_2_Y*BEACON_2_Y;
        double D = 2*BEACON_3_X - 2*BEACON_2_X;
        double E = 2*BEACON_3_Y - 2*BEACON_3_X;
        double F = d2*d2 - d3*d3 - BEACON_2_X*BEACON_2_X + BEACON_3_X*BEACON_3_X - BEACON_2_Y*BEACON_2_Y + BEACON_3_Y*BEACON_3_Y;
        SCANNER_X = (C*E - F*B) / (E*A - B*D);
        SCANNER_Y = (C*D - A*F) / (B*D - A*E);
    }
```

Anyway, my problem here is that the
`curr_dist = Double.parseDouble(df.format(beacon.getDistance()));` is not accurate at all.

```
    /**
     * Provides a calculated estimate of the distance to the beacon based on a running average of
     * the RSSI and the transmitted power calibration value included in the beacon advertisement.
     * This value is specific to the type of Android device receiving the transmission.
     *
     * @see #mDistance
     * @return distance
     */
    public double getDistance() {
        if (mDistance == null) {
            double bestRssiAvailable = mRssi;
            if (mRunningAverageRssi != null) {
                bestRssiAvailable = mRunningAverageRssi;
            }
            else {
                LogManager.d(TAG, "Not using running average RSSI because it is null");
            }
            mDistance = calculateDistance(mTxPower, bestRssiAvailable);
        }
        return mDistance;
    }
```

I can have a beacon at 3m and get estimations that it is at 6m or so. I can have a beacon at 0.3m and get an estimation of 2.5m. My point is that this function doesn't work for me. I don't know if I am doing something wrong or is it some fault of AltBeacon or is it just impossible to get a correct distance. If you know any way to get more accurate distance estimates I would appreciate it. It can be a library or a manual way. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**You have to set your expectations when using Bluetooth distance estimates**.  The word estimate is used for a reason -- the value will never be highly accurate.  Under ideal conditions, they will give you a general idea of distance (e.g. it estimate 1-5 meters when you are really two meters away).  As you have seen, **this isn't accurate enough to work well for techniques for trilateration**.

I wrote [a deep dive explaining why distance estimates are not more accurate](http://www.davidgyoungtech.com/2020/05/15/how-far-can-you-go), the steps you can take to make them as accurate as possible, what you shouldn't do with them, and why they are still very valuable for some use cases.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer. I have actually read your article in the past and I was trying to explain to my professor that it is not my fault that I don't get good estimates but he said that it can't be that bad and I should review my algorithm. So basically it is not my fault and it is normal getting estimations of -+3m right?

Comment: If you calibrate your beacons and adjust for phone receiver variations you should be able to get +/- 1 meter at close distances of 1-2 meters and lear line of sight.  It sounds like you have not done that optimization to make the distance estimates as accurate as possible.  But even if you did, I don't believe you will do better than +/- 1 meter.  And I don't think that will be good enough for your use case.